# mysql: order by match

Tags: php, mysql

for looking up matching keywords in mysql i use

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `keywords` REGEXP '.*(word1|word2|word3).*' LIMIT 1
```

I want to order them by the most matching keywords in the keywords column to give the best answer.For example

> Keywords  ///////////////  Response
>   word1,word2 /////////// test1
>   word1,word2,word3 / test2

I want the response to be test2 with the query given.
How can i order the results my the most matching keywords?

Comment: Is the column `keywords` a comma separated list or free text?

Comment: **Is storing a comma separated list in a database column really that bad?:**

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-comma-separated-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  (keywords REGEXP '.*(word1).*')
  +(keywords REGEXP '.*(word2).*')
  +(keywords REGEXP '.*(word3).*') as number_of_matches
  ,keywords
  ,field1
  ,field2
FROM test 
WHERE keywords REGEXP '.*(word1|word2|word3).*'
ORDER BY number_of_matches DESC 
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```